# php preg_replace subpattern

Tags: php, regex

I would like to highlight the last slug in url like this:

http://www.domain.org/**school**.html

Here's the pattern to capture the slug:

```
$pattern = "/\/([^/]+)\.html$/";
```

How do I run preg_replace on url to replace the slug with `<b>slug</b>`?

Comment: What you are describing isn't a slug, it's a filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to preserve the / and filename suffix then for replacement:

```
= preg_replace("~(/)([^/]+)(\.html)$~", "$1<b>$2</b>$3", $urltext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simple as this - see examples on php site

```
preg_replace( $pattern, "<b>\$1</b>", $input );
```

Comment: @Dziamid Just add the missing `/` to the replacement, like `"/<b>\$1</b>"`.